# Virtualbox Linux: How to keep NumLock ON

Tags: virtualbox, numlock

My system is a Windows OS. However, every time I am using Linux on Virtualbox, as soon as I switch from VirtualBox to another (host machine's) windows program, my NumLock is off.

I could have NumLock on in Linux (VirtualBox), but it turns off when switching back to any Windows program.
**Is there a way to keep NumLock on regardless?**

Comment: The normal way this works is to enable Num Lock in the Host and enable it again in the Guest.  The setting does not transfer (by design).

Comment: @John Is there a way to have NumLock on at boot?

Comment: try: VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" GUI/HidLedsSync "1"  from: https://martinvanbeurden.nl/blog/virtualbox-numlock-weirdness/

Comment: I've seen the same behaviour in Hyper-V on Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Answer (score 4):

NumLock problems have plagued VirtualBox for more than a decade.
Periodically they were fixed, only to reappear again in the next
release.
It seems that it's quite complicated to keep account of this state
when focus and NumLock state may change by a simple movement of
the cursor.

The article
[VirtualBox numlock weirdness](https://martinvanbeurden.nl/blog/virtualbox-numlock-weirdness/)
by Martin van Beurden from 2015 claims to have found this solution:

> After upgrading to VirtualBox 5 on Windows every time I started,
> focused or unfocused a virtual machine my numlock status would toggle.
> If you're having the same problem here is how to fix it:
>
> ```
> VBoxManage setextradata "<machine-name>" GUI/HidLedsSync "0"
> ```
>
> This will disable keyboard indicators (HID LEDs) synchronization. This
> setting it supposed to be disabled by default but for some reason it
> was not on my installation. VBoxManage is located where you installed
> virtualbox, usually `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox`.
>
> If you have a lot of virtual machines you can process them all by
> running the following commands:
>
> 1. Open a command prompt
> 2. Add virtualbox to you path:
>
>    ```
>    set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
>    ```
> 3. Go to the directory where you're virtual machines are located, commands below are for a default install:
>
>    ```
>    %HOMEDRIVE%
>    cd "%HOMEPATH%\VirtualBox VMs"
>    ```
> 4. Update the setting for all machines in the directory
>
>    ```
>    for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b /a:d ".\*"') do (VBoxManage setextradata "%G" GUI/HidLedsSync "0")
>    ```
>
> Hooray, no more numlock weirdness.

I'm not using VirtualBox, so cannot test if this 2015 fix still works.

Comment: Will test it out tonight, before the bounty expires

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows 10 and VirtualBox 7.0

Answer (score 1):

The free software [NumLocker](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/NumLocker.shtml) can keep your NumLock always on (or always off).

If you need more control, you could consider the PRO (paid) version of [TrayStatus](https://www.traystatus.com/), which according to the website allows you

> to automatically enable or disable Caps/Num/Scroll Lock when specific
> applications or windows are focused.

Note: I'm not associated in any way with these softwares.